# boost shared_ptr turns invalid on program exit

Tags: boost, memory-leaks, initialization, shared-ptr

I ran into a problem with a dirty shutdown of my program, because of a shared pointer. I found a solution, but I'm not sure, if I have the right answer.

This is the minimalistic example:

```
double var;
boost::shared_ptr<const double> ptr1 (&var); // creates an invalid pointer on program exit
boost::shared_ptr<const double> ptr2 (new double); // works fine

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  return 0;
}
```

Here is my answer which I would like to varify:

In the case of `ptr1` the pointed-to object will be deleted before the pointer, which then points to an invalid address. But in the case of `ptr2` the "smartness" of the shared pointer handles the issue above.
True?

Small extra question:
Is there a way to make ptr1 work (I tried `reset()`) or is that bad programming practice (if so why)?

Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Its wrong to take address of stack variable and pass into shared_ptr

Comment: @PSIAlt, that's not a stack variable it's a global, but the point is that it's not dynamically-allocated, so must not be owned by a `shared_ptr` with a default deleter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the first case, the pointer isn't dynamically allocated, so the shared_ptr should not attempt to destroy the underlying object. that can be done by using a custom no-op deleter functor:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/smart_ptr/sp_techniques.html#static